# Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильнее это сократить

Tags: python

Душой чувствую, что можно сделать эффективнее, а знания не позволяют

```py
admins = []
for admin in db.get_admins():          # db.get_admins() = [(56564444, 775171777), (775171777, 775171777)]
    if admin[1] == message.from_user.id:    # 775171777
        admins.append(admin[0])
print(admins)                # [56564444, 775171777]
```

В комментах приведены конкретные примеры значений

Comment: Возможно ничего исправлять и не нужно, я не уверен, по этому и спрашиваю
Под эффективней я имею ввиду короче, красивее, правильней

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно сократить до одной строчки, используя генератор списков, это и на немного ускорит код:

```py
admins = [admin for admin, message_id in db.get_admins() if message_id == message.from_user.id]
```

Comment: Я бы ещё избавился от индексов, сразу распаковывая `for` в две переменные, только непонятно тут, как их нормально назвать

Comment: @CrazyElf можно назвать admin и message_id, и индексы уйдут. Сейчас исправлю решение.

Comment: обожаю comprehension 

Comment: @Bol4onok Наверное, это всё же `user_id`, но это уже не суть важно )